# Functions stored in array is echoing without echoing the array

Tags: php, arrays

I have some functions such as `type`,`hint`. like

```
function type($num,$a) {
    if ( $num & 1 ) {
        echo position($num,$a).' digit is odd number<br/>';
    } else {
        echo position($num,$a).' digit is even number<br/>';
    }
}
```

Now I want to store these functions in an array like this

```
$array = array(
    'f1' => hint($a2,$a),
    'f2' => type($a2,$a),
    'f3' => len($a2,$a),
);
```

Now I want the array values to be displayed as

```
echo $array['f1'];
```

But the problem is without this `echo $array['f1'];` statement, the `$array` itself echoing the function values together which I don't want.
 I can solve this problem by output buffering. But I think this is not the correct way to do so.  What should I do to echo the array values when I need them.

Comment: `return` the values in your function, then you can echo it out whenever you so desire later.

Comment: Yes bro. Its working now. Thanks. I should have thought this simple idea.